# Why is this line run twice and with abnormal behavior?

Tags: c++

To preface, I've fairly recently begun self studying programming and thus am just about as novice as they get. If you notice any bad general coding practices in my code (inc. irrelevant to my question) please let me know, since I honestly probably don't know any better.

Onto the question:

I'm trying to make a short snippet of code to replace occurrences of a target string with a new string. I'm aware that there exist functions which would greatly improve the process (i.e. find, replace, etc), for the purposes of the exercise I'm avoiding those and limiting myself to using iterators, insert, and erase. I also know that there are many other places where the code could be improved and I'd love input on those parts as well, but I am primarily concerned with what I find to be anomalous behavior. What I have right now is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool scan(const std::string, const std::string::iterator);

//replaces occurrences of oldVal in s with newVal
std::string& replace (std::string &s, const std::string &oldVal, const std::string &newVal) 
{
    std::string::iterator iter = s.begin();
    while (iter != s.end()) { //process s
        if (scan(oldVal, iter)) { //Checks if characters match
            iter = s.erase(iter, iter + oldVal.size()); //deletes occurrence of oldVal
            iter = s.insert(iter, newVal.begin(), newVal.end()); //inserts newVal in oldVal's place
            iter = iter + newVal.size(); //continues processing after inserted newVal
        }
        else
            ++iter; //Move to next character in s to process
    }
    return s;
}

//This function returns 1 if the strings match and 0 if they do not
bool scan(const std::string target, std::string::iterator iter)
{
    for (auto beg = target.begin(); beg != target.end(); ++beg) {
        std::cout << "Line 27 " << *iter << " " << *beg << std::endl; //MAIN CONCERN! This line is run twice. 
                                                                      //(It was solely added for debugging. Verifies values being compared)
        if (*iter != *beg) {
            std::cout << "Condition met; " 
                      << *iter << " != " << *beg << std::endl; //added for debugging. Double verifies values post-comparison
            return 0;
            }
        ++iter;
        ++beg;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    std::string mainStr, oldStr, newStr;
    std::getline(std::cin, mainStr); //Overall it'd be better for s to be a list of strings, but my concern is with line 27
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin >> oldStr >> newStr;
    std::cout << "Output: " << replace(mainStr, oldStr, newStr) << std::endl; //Prints post-replacement string
}
```

What appears to be happening is that line 27 (std::cout << "Line 27 " ...) is executed twice the first time scan is called. For example, given input:

```
tho
tho though
```

I get the output (//are comments I'm adding in outside of the run, i.e. just for this post)

```
Line 27 t t //This part is run twice and does weird things
Line 27 h o //If it was just incrementing it should read "Line 27 h h"
Condition met; h != o //This shouldn't happen; The condition should have tested t != t
Line 27 h t //It's seems fine from this point onwards
Condition failed; h != t
Line 27 o t
Condition failed; o != t
Output: tho
```

What could be the cause of this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why it is voted to close. It seems on topic. I haven't tried running it but seems like @tea has tried to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the provided code.  The main issues is in 'scan(...)', where you're incremeneting the 'beg' iterator twice each time around the loop, once in the for() construct:

```
for (auto beg = target.begin(); beg != target.end(); ++beg)
```

and once at the end of the for loop:

```
++iter;
++beg;
```

A couple of minor points in the scan(...) function would be to pass 'target' as a reference (const std::string& target), and return false/true, not 0/1.

I checked this on Ubuntu 12.04 using g++-4.8, and that seems to use the c++98 definition for insert, which doesn't return an interator (i.e. the function is "void insert (iterator p, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);").... Here's the code modified slightly to work around this problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool scan(const std::string&, const std::string::iterator);

//replaces occurrences of oldVal in s with newVal
std::string& replace (std::string &s, const std::string &oldVal, const std::string &newVal)
{
    std::string::iterator iter = s.begin();
    while (iter != s.end()) { //process s
        if (scan(oldVal, iter)) { //Checks if characters match
            iter = s.erase(iter, iter + oldVal.size()); //deletes occurrence of oldVal
            // Doesn't work on g++4.8 on Ubuntu, still seems to use the c++98 "void insert (iterator p, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);"
            //iter = s.insert(iter, newVal.begin(), newVal.end()); //inserts newVal in oldVal's place

            // If the iter == s.end(), then pos will not be the value we need.
            size_t pos = iter == s.end()? s.size() : std::distance(s.begin(), iter);
            s.insert(iter, newVal.begin(), newVal.end()); //inserts newVal in oldVal's place
            iter = s.begin() + pos;
            iter = iter + newVal.size(); //continues processing after inserted newVal
        }
        else
            ++iter; //Move to next character in s to process
    }
    return s;
}

//This function returns 1 if the strings match and 0 if they do not
bool scan(const std::string& target, std::string::iterator iter)
{
    for (auto beg = target.begin(); beg != target.end(); ++beg) {
        std::cout << "Line 27 " << *iter << " " << *beg << std::endl; //MAIN CONCERN! This line is run twice.
                                                                      //(It was solely added for debugging. Verifies values being compared)
        if (*iter != *beg) {
            std::cout << "Condition met; "
                      << *iter << " != " << *beg << std::endl; //added for debugging. Double verifies values post-comparison
            return false;
            }
        ++iter;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::string mainStr, oldStr, newStr;
    std::getline(std::cin, mainStr); //Overall it'd be better for s to be a list of strings, but my concern is with line 27
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin >> oldStr >> newStr;
    std::cout << "Output: " << replace(mainStr, oldStr, newStr) << std::endl; //Prints post-replacement string
}
```

Comment: Thanks (both you and cudahead)! The double ++beg was exactly my problem. Is it generally considered better to give bools true and false instead of 1 and 0? If so, is there a particular reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

One bug that I found: In `scan()` the `beg` iterator is increased twice in each iteration, due to `++beg` in `for(...)` loop line and `beg++` at the end of the loop.